# "base" is a missing Package for context in tex

Tags: errors, packages

How can I install "base" folder for the contex in tex folder.

I think this "base" is different from the "base" in Latex.

Pleas see the picture and error..[image]

Comment: It seems you are using MiKTeX basic installation. Please install MiKTeX complete, run the Package Manager!

Comment: I don't use miktex but surely your screen shot is not showing an error and the answer to "how can I install"  should be "click the button that says `install`" ? Did you try clicking the install button, what happened?